# Is MPI shared memory a good solution for my problem?

Tags: matrix, fortran, mpi, shared-memory

I have several processes, each of them calculates certain sub-matrices of one global matrix. The problem is that the sub-matrices will overlap and in general they do not necessarily have to form a continuous block within the global matrix. Also each tasks might also have more than one sub-matrix.

Finally, in order to obtain my final matrix I need to perform an element wise summation of these sub-matrices by considering the position within the global matrix.

So far I am doing the following:

- each processor has its own copy of the global array (matrix)
- each processor then calculates a sub-matrix of that global matrix and adds the elements to the right position in the local copy of the global array
- with mpi_allreduce I am obtaining the final global matrix synchronized over all the tasks (this is my element wise summation to obtain my final result)

This works reasonably well as long as my global matrix is small. However, this becomes quickly a memory bottleneck as allocating local copies of the global matrix becomes more and more expensive.

One constraint is that I have to solve this with MPI only.
Another constraint is that I need to perform operations on that global matrix afterwards. Where different task have access (this time read-only) different parts of that global matrix. The blocks are not the same as the sub-matrix blocks before.

I somehow stumbled along MPI-3 shared memory arrays. However, I am not sure if this might be the best solution for my problem as several processes have to add simultaneously small local arrays which overlap. However, for my operations afterwards, each process could also read from that global matrix again.

I am relatively inexperienced how to solve these kind of problems and I would be happy for any kind of suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: With MPI whenever you want each process to have a complete copy of a memory constraining data structure, such as your matrix here, you are almost always doing it wrong. What do you want to do with this matrix once you have generated it? Keep your large objects distributed!

Comment: I totally agree, my hands are just somehow tied by the routines and data layout of the software package I am going to implement this. Once I have this global matrix, each process then gets a block of this matrix. However, these blocks are completely different from the blocks I have to use in constructing these matrix. Unfortunately, the software packages forces me to actually change the data layout twice.

Comment: In the read-only part, does each task/process access the same subblock one-or-more times, or do they dance all over the matrix? (And I'm curious: what is the application?)

Comment: I think, provided there is not huge overlap between the blocks, I would generate something like a linked list of local blocks, only storing what is required for each block on the process, and then redistribute that into the global *distributed* form. Replicated matrices are just not scalable - inefficient means you have to wait for an answer, insufficient memory means you *can never get an answer*.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! In the read-only part each task needs to access it's sub-block once. The matrix is involved in calculating excited states for semiconductors or excited states of very large molecules.

Comment: [@blub8819 for more discussions, this discourse site may also be useful https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/